# Не загружаются переменные окружения

Tags: python, python-3.x, variable, .env, environment-variables

Использую `dotenv`. Загружаю переменные окружения из `test.env`. Покажу моё дерево со структурой проекта

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В переменных окружения пишу путь к переменным в переменной `ENV_FILE`. Путь задаю так: `../.envs/test.env`

При этом, явно указываю `PYTHONPATH=./`

В таком случае, ни одно переменная не подтягивается.

В чём проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в том, указывать путь к проекту нужно глобальный. Иными словами, следует сделать так:

```
ENV_FILE=../.envs/test.env
PYTHONPATH=/home/eurvanov/python/email-client/
```